# Using the `geometry` package with luatex

Tags: luatex, geometry

According to [the `geometry` package's user manual](http://ftp.cc.uoc.gr/mirrors/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/geometry/geometry.pdf) (2010/09/12 v5.6, section 5.6 'Drivers', p. 11)

> The package supports drivers `dvips`, `dvipdfm`, `pdftex`, `xetex`, and `vtex`.

Can I use this package with `luatex`? If so - which driver should I specify? If not - what are the alternatives?

Comment: Yes, you can use it with lualatex. Just as usual. Please consider the 'age' of `geometry`'s last release: Almost seven years, i.e. at a time when `lua(la)tex` was very young and Hideo Umeki possibly just forgot to change the quoted line

Comment: Or Hideo Umeki was not aware about Lua(La)TeX at all...

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As with graphics and color it is usually best not to specify a driver at all and let the system detect what you are using. Unfortunately however `geometry` has not been updated to luatex 0.85 and later so you need to use

```
\RequirePackage{luatex85}
```

as the first line of the document to offer a compatibility layer, `geometry` will then work using the `pdftex` driver files.

**`luatex85` is no longer required with `geometry` 2018/03/24 v5.7**

Comment: Is there any alternative for the `geometry` package that works with the current `luatex` engine?

Comment: @EvanAad you can always set the lower level settings for the margins text block and page width directly, but using luatex85 package is fine, basically you just need the old name `\pdfpagewidth` to be defined as an alias of  the new name `\pagewidth` that's the only change the package needs, it's frustrating that it's not been updated

Answer (score 5):

Adding to David Carlisle's answer, I found that I can get `geometry` to work with the latest LuaTeX (1.0.4) as long as I also use one of `graphicx` or `color` / `xcolor`.

Perhaps these packages detect the `luatex` driver so that `geometry` doesn't have to? I'm not expert enough to say, but that's my guess.