# Lualatex: can't landscape

Tags: luatex, landscape

Below is minimum code. If I compile by `pdflatex`, landscape worked. If I compile by `lualatex`, landscape didn't work. So, how to make `landscape` work with `lualatex`? Thank you.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[margin=5.0mm,landscape]{geometry}
\begin{document}
\subsection[Dead load]{Dead load}

\end{document}
```

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/373926/using-the-geometry-package-with-luatex

Comment: @Joseph Wright Thanks a lot. It works. In fact, I have done a lot of search. But my key word is lualatex, and I am not lucky to find the link. Thank you once again.